# how to set Progress Bar value in vb6

Tags: vb6, progress-bar

when I copy the file from one folder to another folder, I want to show the progress bar.

```
Open Text1.Text For Binary Access Read As FF
filedata = Space(LOF(FF))
Get #1, 1, filedata
Close #FF

Open Text1.Text & ".copy.exe" For Binary Access Write As FF
Put #FF, 1, filedata
Close #FF
```

How to add Progress Bar for this...

Answer (score 1):

If these files are so large or the drives so slow that it makes any sense to show a progress bar then copy in smaller chunks.  If things take that long then you'll be better off handling each chunk prompted by a Timer tick anyway.  Update the ProgressBar, etc. each completed tick.  In this way you won't need an Evil `DoEvents()` call and your UI and program remain responsive to a Cancel button.